# Swift - Custom color not applying to barTintColor

Tags: swift, user-interface, uinavigationbar, uicolor, bartintcolor

In a view controller embedded in a navigation controller I am attempting to change the `barTintColor` to a custom color. What I have experienced is if I use a default color such as the one below, the color is actually applied:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

However when I try to create an instance of my own custom color such as this code would show, the color is not applied:

```
let customRedColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 0, blue: 13, alpha: 1 )
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = customRedColor
```

I am very curious as to why the custom color is not being applied to the navigation bar so that leads me to ask:

What approach should be taken in order to correctly apply a custom color to the navigation bars barTintColor property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give color by dividing them by `255`, the syntax is like this.

```
init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```

Each of the ones that take a `CGFloat` take a value between ***0.0 and 1.0***, referring to either the complete absence of, or the maximum amount of that color component respectively.  So, this means that even if you have pure `RGB` values in decimal or hexadecimal format, you will have to divide them by decimal 255 to get the amount to input here.

```
let customRedColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0 , green: 0, blue: 13/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
//or Direct
let customRedColor = UIColor(red: 1.0 , green: 0, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = customRedColor
```

Comment: Aye, worked and super simple solution. I appreciate it, I'll mark as correct as soon as SO allows me to in 5 minutes.

Comment: You should divide it by 255.0 to make it float, otherwise you'll lose precision.